# big issue in converting string to datetime using linq-to-entities

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

How can I convert the string to datetime using linq to entities ....

I have got the below query, where the `visit_date` column datatype is string...

```
var memberl = from v in abc.visits
              join m in abc.members on v.member_Id equals m.member_Id
              where Convert.ToDateTime(v.visit_Date) >= startdate && 
                    Convert.ToDateTime(v.visit_Date) <= enddate
              group m by new { m.member_Firstname, 
                               m.member_Lastname, m.member_Id } into g
              orderby g.Count()
              select new
              {
                  numVisits = g.Count(),
                  firstname = g.Key.member_Firstname,
                  lastname = g.Key.member_Lastname
              };
```

Unfortunately I can't change the schema ...

I have got the error:

```
linq to entites does not recognise Convert.ToDatetime method
```

Is there any possible solution for converting string to Datetime?

**Updated code:**

as per request i  Have updated my question

```
 var data = (from v in abc.visits
                  join m in abc.members on v.member_Id equals m.member_Id
                  select new
                  {
                      MemberID = v.member_Id,
                      VisiteDate = v.visit_Date,
                      FirstName = m.member_Firstname,
                      LastName = m.member_Lastname
                  }).ToList();

      var membersdata = from d in data
                        where Convert.ToDateTime(d.VisiteDate) >= startdate && Convert.ToDateTime(d.VisiteDate) <= enddate
                        group m by new { d.FirstName, d.LastName, d.MemberID } into g
                        orderby g.Count()
                        select new
                        {
                            numVisits = g.Count(),
                            firstname = g.Key.FirstName,
                            lastname = g.Key.LastName
                        };
```

Comment: It's the price of storing dates as string... It doesn't follow the yyyyMMdd form by chance?

Comment: Perhaps look into **model defined functions** to handle situations where you can do something in TSQL (`CAST(text as datetime)`) but not in EF (`Convert.ToDateTime(text)`). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456857.aspx

Comment: What is this updated code now? It's impossible that you get your exception with that code. The second query isn't LINQ to Entities anymore, it's LINQ to Objects in memory and there `Convert.ToDateTime` works. Can you please check the code you have posted?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't think EF supports a translation for a String to DateTime or vice-versa conversion.

As I see it, you have two options, depending on the format of the date in the string field:

If the format is fairly simple, a string comparison might be enough:

```
// Convert the boundaries to strings first
// TODO: Set the ToString format option to match the database format
string startDateAsString = startdate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
string endDateAsString = enddate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");

// Query based on string comparison
var memberl = from v in abc.visits
              join m in abc.members on v.member_Id equals m.member_Id
              where v.visit_Date.CompareTo(startDateAsString) >= 0 && 
                    v.visit_Date.CompareTo(endDateAsString) <= 0
              group m by new { m.member_Firstname, 
                               m.member_Lastname, m.member_Id } into g
              orderby g.Count()
              select new
              {
                  numVisits = g.Count(),
                  firstname = g.Key.member_Firstname,
                  lastname = g.Key.member_Lastname
              };
```

If the string representation of the date is more complex, and a simple string comparison cannot help, you might consider creating a `view` on the `visits` table, which does the conversion for you at database level:

```
CREATE VIEW VisitsWithDate (MemberId, VisitDate)
AS
SELECT MemberId, Convert(datetime, VisitDate, 112) -- For instance
FROM Visits
```

Followed by importing this view into your DataModel. You might need to do some magic to make the relationships work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @errorcode105: I would test the date comparisons thoroughly, because comparing them as strings is not guaranteed to be accurate.

Comment: Agree. The caveat with the first solution is certainly the date format

Answer (score 3):

`Convert.ToDatetime` is supported by Linq2SQL. The only supported method of Linq to entities are these:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx

about your problem ... try to convert `startdate` and `enddate` in string and compare the string value in linq expression.

Answer (score 2):

Try converting the results to a `List<>` first, and filter the results from the list:

```
var data = (from v in abc.visits 
            join m in abc.members on v.member_Id equals m.member_Id
            select new
            {
                MemberID = v.member_id,
                VisiteDate = v.visit_date,
                FirstName = m.member_FirstName,
                LastName = m.member_LastName
            }).ToList();    


var memberl = from d in data    
              where Convert.ToDateTime(d.VisitDate) >= startdate && Convert.ToDateTime(d.VisitDate) <= enddate           
              group d by new { d.FirstName, d.LastName, d.MemberID } into g           
              orderby g.Count()           
              select new           
              {           
                  numVisits = g.Count(),           
                  firstname = g.Key.FirstName,           
                  lastname = g.Key.LastName           
              };
```

Comment: Convert.ToDateTime(v.visit_Date) >= startdate && Convert.ToDateTime(v.visit_Date) <= enddate  this line is not work any more using entities ..

Comment: Sorry, just updated my answer. Needed to select the necessary columns when converting it to a list.

Comment: I have got the error at this line        "group m by new { d.FirstName, d.LastName, d.MemberID } into g"   Saying that "cannot convert lambda expression to type system.Collections.Generic.IequalityComparer<anonymousType#2> because it is not a delegate type"  would you pls help on ths...

Comment: I think there's something you're missing in your code. Can you revise your question and post your updated code?

Comment: Found the issue: Change `group m by` to `group d by` and you should be all set.

Comment: This doesn't seem like the best idea, you would be querying in memory. And the query doesn't get any more readable this way :-)

Comment: @YannickMotton: I'm more concerned with making it workable right now. Obviously, if OP can return a DateTime from the database that would be much easier, but as is my solution seems to be the most common.

Comment: I have proposed two alternate solutions which do the comparison at database side which also *work*

Comment: @YannickMotton: As I said in my comment, doing it at the database level would be ideal, but we don't know whether that's possible yet. He said he can't change the schema, so for all we know he can't use a view.

Comment: It's a solution but you really must emphasize in the answer that a whole unfiltered collection is loaded into memory first *before* the filter gets applied. Beginners might easily oversee the difference. Imagine this table has a million records. The next question we have to expect then is: "Why is my query which only returns two objects so slow and does consume so much memory?" :)

Answer (score 0):

Because DateTime and DateTimeOffset are structs, they are not intrinsically nullable.
When you need nullability, there are two ways around this:

1. Use a Nullable type (i.e., DateTime? or DateTimeOffset?).
2. Use the static field DateTime.MinValue or DateTimeOffset.MinValue (the default
   values for these types)