# Linq: Sort by Date when its stored as text

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, linq-to-entities

I need to sort by date but the date is stored as text in the database. I am using Linq to entities to perform queries.

The way the database is designed it is not feasible to change the column to a date column because many different data types are in that column. There is a descriminator column named `type` so I will know what type a particular row is.

Comment: What do you want to do with the non-date values? Drop them?

Comment: In my query, I will be selecting only date values because I will have a type in a different column that tells me what type the data column is

Comment: @Luke101 first  retrieve all records from database to list and then do operations on that list(like sorting ...)

Comment: I have about 90,000 rows and this will take the website down if I do this?

Comment: @Luke101 take a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740693/big-issue-in-converting-string-to-datetime-using-linq-to-entities

Comment: @Luke101 sorry i dont know any other options .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a computed column to the table that will convert those strings to dates when your discriminator has a specific value (here I've just used `'date'`).

```
ALTER TABLE Foo
ADD trueDate AS
    CASE 
        WHEN type = 'date' THEN CONVERT(date, 'mixedColumn', 101)
        ELSE NULL
    END
PERSISTED
```

If you have time information, then `date` should be `datetime` in the `CONVERT()` function.

Also, the `101` is a style code indicating an expected format of `MM/dd/yyyy`. If you have something different, refer to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx, but keep in mind that if you use a style below 100 your expression will be considered non-deterministic and you cannot make your computed column `PERSISTED`, so the conversions will be done on the fly with each query (you don't want that).

The computed column will update itself when the row values change; otherwise the values are persisted and queryable just like in any other column. No triggers required.

Comment: Wow..nice. One more thing. Can I put an index on that column. I will store dates, integers, strings and other data types. I would like to index the column with different data types. is this possible?

Comment: @Luke101 The column with different data types can be indexed, but will only be indexed as varchar. To be clear, the computed column is an *added* column that contains only dates where the discriminator indicates date and otherwise null. You can create indexes on a computed column as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If all your rows containing dates use the same date format you could just order by their string value. But since the most common (i.e english) date format does NOT start with the year, that could prove problematic.

**Option A.: Sort in memory.**

```
var records = db.YourTable.Where(o=>o.Discriminator =="date").AsEnumerable()
    .Select(o=>new {Entity= o, Date=DateTime.Parse(o.YourColumn)})
    .OrderBy(o.Date).Select(o=>o.Entity);
```

*Do NOT do this if you have a lot of rows, or if you have to, at least have the decency to cache the ordered result...*

**Option B.: Database magic**
Add an extra column to your DB, make THAT Date (nullable), and update that if the discriminator is date. You can either update it in a (DML) *Trigger* or from *C#*...
OR if the conversion is simple you could build a *view* out of it...