# Computed column with different data types

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want a computed column to have several data types and be able to index them. This question is related to this SO post: [Linq: Sort by Date when its stored as text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198345/linq-sort-by-date-when-its-stored-as-text)

Here is my database setup:

```
id INT
type INT
data computed column
```

Here is some sample data that might go in this table

```
id---------type--------data
1----------1-----------190
2----------2-----------9/29/1972
3----------3-----------12.72
4----------1-----------2
5----------4-----------this is a test
```

As you can see the `data` column has several data types. I wanted to know how do i implement a system like this and put an index the `data` column as the datatype it should be. For example,

- Type is 1: Then the index will be INT
- Type is 2: Then the index will be DATE or DATETIME
- Type is 3: Then the index will be DECIMAL
  and so on

Is it possible to give the computed column an index on several different data types? If so, how might I do this?
 - then the index will be an inte

Comment: This is an EAV and is an anti-pattern of what *not* to do

Comment: To do this you'll have to make `data` a varchar column and then figure out the data type programatically. You can't index "by datatype" though because it can't have multiple data types on one column.

Comment: What are you hoping to actually achieve?  Only that as 'gbn' has pointed out raises an implementation/design pattern issue.  If you can explain what you are trying to achieve there maybe a more suitable approach.

Answer (score 4):

A column has a single datatype, not several. You **can not** do what you ask.

Your design is an EAV and is an [anti-pattern](http://karwin.blogspot.com/2009/05/eav-fail.html)

If you insist, you can add more computed columns based on the single varchar type. But then why not have them in the first place? Or use an indexed view to cast and index?

Comment: +1 - This is a fairly ridiculous design concept.  If he wanted it to work he could just make a field for each data type, but it's still a terrible idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use diffirent datatypes for a column