# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.String)' method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to convert one application to EntityFrameWork codefirst.
My present code is

```
 string sFrom  ="26/12/2013";
 select * FROM Trans where  CONVERT(datetime, Date, 105) >=   CONVERT(datetime,'" + sFrom + "',105)
```

And i tried

```
 DateTime dtFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(sFrom );
TransRepository.Entities.Where(x  =>Convert.ToDateTime(x.Date) >= dtFrom)
```

But I got an error like this

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime
>   ToDateTime(System.String)' method

Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [big issue in converting string to datetime using linq-to-entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740693/big-issue-in-converting-string-to-datetime-using-linq-to-entities)

Comment: I found this to be a very simple workaround without going through a lot of hassle.
[Use SqlFunctions.DateAdd with a 0 interval](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33443127)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

when you do this:

```
TransRepository.Entities.Where(x  =>Convert.ToDateTime(x.Date) >= dtFrom)
```

LINQ to Entities cannot translate most .NET Date methods (including the casting you used) into SQL since there is no equivalent SQL.
What you need to do is to do below:

```
 DateTime dtFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(sFrom );
  TransRepository
 .Entities.ToList()//forces execution
 .Where(x  =>Convert.ToDateTime(x.Date) >= dtFrom)
```

but wait the above query will fetch **entire data**, and perform `.Where` on it, definitely  you don't want that,

simple soultion would be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740693/big-issue-in-converting-string-to-datetime-using-linq-to-entities), 
personally, I would have made my Entity field as `DateTime` and db column as `DateTime`

but since, your db/Entity `Date` field is string, you don't have any other option, other than to change your field in the entity and db to `DateTime` and then do the comparison

Comment: No, don't do that. It will bring the entire table content into memory and perform filtering in memory using LINQ to Objects.

Comment: In that case you get all the data to the client which may not be the desired behavior, especially if the table contains several millions of records.

Comment: @ManishMishra You're answer is not done? Don't post it. But even with the update, I don't agree and I think OP should not follow your advice.

Comment: hey, what he should follow or not doesn't matter, I am trying to explain, why the error is there and how to see it go away

Comment: 1. Your explanation is wrong. No SQL is generated at all, nothing is sent to SQL Server either. LINQ to Entities is not able to generate proper SQL at all. 2. Getting rid of error in a way you suggested gives OP a ton of other problems, with a huge performance issue as the  most important one. 3. There are other ways of working that problem around, you can read about them here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740693/big-issue-in-converting-string-to-datetime-using-linq-to-entities

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, yes you are right, my explanation was wrong, I hope it is right now

Comment: Thanks to Manish Mishra and MarcinJuraszek .Manish Mishra's solution got the error away. I got another solution from the link provided. Changed my code  . It works fine :-) Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Why is your date column a string?  Shouldn't it be a `DateTime`?

Regardless, if you attempt to perform conversions using .NET functions in a .Where statement against a repository of entities, you'll get that error.

Your best option would be to change that column from a string to a DateTime and proceed from there.  If you do, the `.Where` statement would be:

```
DateTime dtFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(sFrom );
var something = TransRepository.Entities.Where(x  => x.Date >= dtFrom) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help .But unfortunately I cannot change column to DateTime

Comment: Why would suggesting changing the database be the "best option"? What are the "not best" options? Most developers don't have the luxury of controlling the datatypes in the database so suggesting he change it as the only offered answer is just bad.

Answer (score 3):

Take the convert part out of linq statement and keep it in a variable, like this:

```
var xyz = Convert.ToDateTime("12/31/2018");
```

and use this variable in the linq statement.

Comment: This was the simplest solution here. You helped me a lot. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

/*i had a similar problem where i was getting a search string and querying a datetime column... see line 4*/

```
1)case "Admission_Date":
2)if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchValue))
3)   {
4)   DateTime dtFrom = 
Convert.ToDateTime(SearchValue); 
wards = from s in db.CORE_DATA_tbl
    where s.Admit_Date == dtFrom
    orderby s.ActionType, s.AdmissionLocation
    select s;
    }
    break;
```

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).