# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.String)' method

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework, datetime

Hello This is my first post here

I'm facing some issue with EF , I have tried the following code in VS 2010 with EF 5 and 6.

I have table called **MYTABLE** and field **ReveivedTime** which varchar(255) but this has Datetime values like **"4/29/2014 12:00:00 AM"**. 
Note : I can not change the DataType and I can not write SP to Convert , I do have limitations, So I do have option to work with LAMBDA

I have tired the following code in **LINQPad 4**  itis working fine  but the same is not working in VS2010 with EF 5/6.

getting error

**LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.**

**Convert.ToDateTime(si.ReceivedTime)** is causing the problem

```
   MYTable
  .Where (
      si => 
            ((Convert.ToDateTime(si.ReceivedTime) >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10)) && 
               (Convert.ToDateTime (si.ReceivedTime) <= DateTime.Now)
            )
   )
   .GroupBy (g => new 
                    {
                        Day = Convert.ToDateTime(g.ReceivedTime).Day,
                        Month = Convert.ToDateTime(g.ReceivedTime).Month,
                        Year = Convert.ToDateTime(g.ReceivedTime).Year,
                        City = g.City,
                    })
   .Select (
      g => 
         new  
         {
           Count = g.Count(),
           g.Key.Day,
           g.Key.Month,
           g.Key.Year,
           g.Key.City,
           Date = Convert.ToDateTime(g.Key.Year  + "/" + g.Key.Month + "/" + g.Key.Day),
         }
   )
   .OrderBy(x => x.Count)
```

Really appreciate your solution and advanced thanks too.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible, but maybe someone has different opinion...

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.String)' method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20797158/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-datetime-todatetimesyste). When asking questions at StackOverflow always check whether it's been asked before.

Comment: This is not duplicate one ... the error may be the same but trying to achieve different...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Convert.ToDateTime (si.ReceivedTime) <= DateTime.Now` try `SqlFunctions.DateDiff("s", si.ReceivedTime, DateTime.Now) > 0`