# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method ToDateTime(System.String)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, datetime

I have to use a "convert to datetime" method to compare the datetime with the reference month and year, as below

```
var res =  db.Table1
//other tables, and where conditions
.Select(x => new MyObj
{
      //...
      Imp = x.MyTable.FirstOrDefault(y => y.date_val >= System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddMonths(Convert.ToDateTime("01/" + x.month + "/" + x.year), 1))).Description
})
```

I know that Convert.ToDateTime can't be translated in sql from the provider, I need an idea to do that query.

UPDATE: I wouldn't materialize the query before the Convert, because that obviously means takes all the records.

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime` couldn't be translated to T-SQL, Linq to Entities couldn't recognize it. Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34061692/2946329

Comment: @S.Akbari Yes I know but I need a workaround or something like that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.String)' method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20797158/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-datetime-todatetimesyste)

Comment: try to use AsEnumerable() to force evaluation of that part with Linq to Objects. so this will become: `x.MyTable.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault.......`... just a thought, haven't tested this with date conversions.

Comment: @Spluf That still brings the entirety of `MyTable` into memory, which isn't generally desirable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I Think I found the way to do it

```
var res =  db.Table1
//other tables, and where conditions
.Select(x => new MyObj
{
      //...
      Imp = x.MyTable.FirstOrDefault(y => y.date_val >= System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddMonths(System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(x.year, x.month, 1, 0, 0, 0), 1)).Description
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a little crude but you can materialise the SQL query to list before you parse the date:

```
var res = db.Table1.ToList()
//other tables, and where conditions
.Select(x => new MyObj
{
//...
    Imp = x.MyTable.FirstOrDefault(y => y.date_val >= System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddMonths(DateTime.Parse("01/" + x.month + "/" + x.year))).Description
})
```

Comment: I wouldn't materialize the query before, if it is possible.