# How to use DateTimeOffset in a C# linq query to the database

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, linq-to-sql, datetimeoffset

I am using entity framework and AutoMapper in my project. In the database DatreTime  fields were initially created as a string type fields and stays the  same (example the fields 'DepartureTime' and 'ArrivalTime'). I am trying to make a DateTime comparison in my solution in a linq query to the dbContext by using DateTimeOffset in an effort to convert the string to a DateTime. But I get an error

The query I'm using is:

```
db.Passengers
.Where(p => p.AreaOfVisit == area && DateTimeOffset.Parse(p.DepartureTime).UtcDateTime > incidentDate &&
                            DateTimeOffset.Parse(p.ArrivalTime).UtcDateTime < incidentDate).ProjectTo<PassengerDTO>()
                .ToList();
```

I get this error message.

> System.NotSupportedException   HResult=0x80131515   Message=LINQ to
>   Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTimeOffset
>   Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression.

What can be the best way to solve this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.String)' method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20797158/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-datetime-todatetimesyste)

Comment: @mjwills p.DepartureTime and p.ArrivalTime are both strings. "incidentDate" is a DateTime which i am trying to the comparison within the linq query

Comment: I'd **strongly** suggest not storing dates as strings in the database. Even if you solve this specific problem, you are going to have endless pain and woe. Bite the bullet now, and move away from strings in the database.

Comment: @MattLuccasPhaureJensen i tried what is said in that article by adjusting the code to db.Passengers
    .Where(p => p.AreaOfVisit == area && Convert.ToDateTime(p.DepartureTime) > incidentDate &&
                Convert.ToDateTime(p.ArrivalTime) < incidentDate).ProjectTo<PassengerDTO>()
    .ToList();          i get the following error : System.NotSupportedException
  LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @sm101 you would have to do the ToList() before the Where because that is what is causing the issue

Comment: Instead of ToDateTime use :  DateTime.Parse(p.ArrivalTime)

Comment: @jdweng tried. Getting this "System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'". Let me try removing the ProjectTo()

Comment: @jdweng n luck getting this "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'"

Comment: Do you need to OFFSET property?

Comment: @mjwills yes according to your advise changed the database field from string type to DateTime. No need of converting inside the linq query now

Comment: Awesome - you have made a wise choice.