# comparing months in words with date in digitd to get data

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Date(String date)
    {
        try
        {
            var users = db.Complains.Where(u => u.Date ==date ).ToList();
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, users);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

In the above code, I am getting the data on entering date in yyy-mm-dd format but my requirement is getting month from user in (January, February) format and showing data of only that month. database picture is attached.

Comment: Images are nearly worthless. [Why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=Images%20are%20harder%20to%20read,actual%20code%20and%20formatting%20it.). Fortunately you seem to have forgotten to upload your image. Your question at this point is not answerable.

Comment: Please share sample of date in Complains table. is it date or just month in database

Comment: the date is store in database as 2022-09-23 but user will be putting month like feburary and I need to fetch data form Complains of that month

Comment: Thanks for quick response.

Comment: Did you try the below solution. did it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algorithm :-

1. First Change name of your parameter 'month'.
2. Then put validation that if value of parameter is not in list of month in string. for that, you can create enum.
3. Set 1, 2...12 values or enum and compare that value in linq to get desire output

   ```
   enum MonthsEnum { Jan=1, Feb=2, Mar=3, Apr=4, May=5, Jun=6, Jul=7, Aug=8, Sep=9, Oct=10, Nov=11, Dec=12 }

   [HttpGet]
   public HttpResponseMessage Date(String month)
   {
       try
       {
           //Convert month in enum;
            Enum.TryParse(month, out MonthsEnum givenMonth);

           if (givenMonth == 0)
             throw new Exception("Invalid Month");

           // if u.Date is date
           var users = db.Complains.Where(u => DateTime.Parse(u.Date).Month == (int)givenMonth).ToList();

          return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, users);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
       }
   }
   ```

`Use date format or culture info in date parse if needed`

See it will work

[image]

Comment: the date is store in database as 2022-09-23  but user will be putting month like feburary and I need to fetch data form Complains of that month

Comment: Thanks for quick response.

Comment: just change name of months in enum to full name then it will work. Please let me know if still you are facing issue.

Comment: did you try this solution?

Comment: thank you for a follow up, and sorry for delayed response I got below response on postman

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: please share error and then if  this method cannot be translated into a store expression. then you need  pass format to convert to date.

Comment: not getting any error on C# end, the response I was getting at postman site I shared already, can you help me completing this Method really struggling with being a biggner

Comment: i cannot see your uploaded image, please upload image as soon as possible

Comment: I have updated answer. I forgot to  add .Month after Date.Parse. it will work. if not then add date format in Date.Parse() still not work then share error or response with me. where did you share response?

Comment: still getting same response at postman  "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.", the data type of date store in the database is varchar don't know if mentioning it will be any help

Comment: First change "db.complain.ToList(). Where(x=> Concert. ToDate(x.date). Month == (inter) givenMonth).[More details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20797158/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-datetime-todatetimesyste).Or you can use sp to fetch data.

Comment: Use one of Convert. ToDate() or Date.Parse(). Convert automatically handle null.

Comment: thank you for your unconditional help, Date.parse() and Convert.ToDate was not accepting only was allowing to select To DateTime(), after implementing this ""db.complain.ToList(). Where(x=> Concert. ToDate(x.date). Month == (inter) givenMonth)" it worked fine for me and got desired result.

Comment: i did accept and upvote it, but can't cast vote due to a low reputation