# How to convert data in sql table into datetime and compare with other value in linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I what to write a linq expression to do the same job like below sql:

```
select * from table where cast(table.field as datetime) > '2015/2/3';
```

I do not konw how to handle the cast function in Linq, please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you cast a `datetime` to `datetime`? Does this work: `var query=table.Where(x => x.create_at > new DateTime(2015,2,3))`?

Comment: the field created_at is not datetime

Comment: Would be interesting to know what it is then. Normally a `CreatedAt`-column is a `datetime`-column. Maybe you should make it one.

Comment: ok, I change created_at to field, It means one not datetime field

Comment: The problem is storing datetime information in a datatype that isn't datetime. Using the proper datatypes eliminates so many challenges.

Comment: OK, I think this one can help me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740693/big-issue-in-converting-string-to-datetime-using-linq-to-entities thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined your column as a `varchar/nvarchar` type and storing date time string in that, you can use this solution.

Assuming you `CreatedDate` column is of type nvarchar and you do not have any NULL values in that.

```
//Get All Id's and Created Date string values

var idAndDates = yourDbContext.Posts
                        .Select(g => new { Id = g.Id, Created = g.CreatedDate}).ToList();

//Convert the string to DateTime and use that to check the condition,
//  Get the Id's of the Records which passed the condition

var postIds = idAndDates
           .Where(g => DateTime.Parse(g.Created) > new DateTime(2015, 2, 3))
           .Select(x => x.Id);

// Query the table again for records matching the Id's we got in previous step.

var filterdPosts= yourDbContext.Posts.Where(x => postIds.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
```

This will execute 2 queries againist your database, one for getting all the Id's and corresponding `CreatedDate` strings. and in C#, We will convert the CreatedDate string to a `DateTime` object and check our if condition and get all the Ids passing the condition. Finally we will use these Ids to query your table again for all records matching those Ids.

Ideally you should not be storing any datetime/timestamp fileds in a varchar type column. You should use the `DateTime`/`DateTime2`/`DateTimeOffset` column types.

If you ever change your `CreatedDate` column to `DateTime` type, You can use the below one line LINQ query to get your records.

```
var posts = yourDbContext.Posts.Where(x => x.CreatedDate > new Dateime(2015,2,3)).ToList();
```

Comment: Any thoughts on whether this is better than just sticking to SQL, assuming the database column can't be changed to datetime? Entity Framework has `SqlQuery` to execute parameterized SQL. My guess is that would be better performance.

Comment: When you use the sql query, you do the conversion in SQL, But will be only one call to SQL server. I would go with that.

Answer (score 0):

I also think, that you should try to store the data as DateTime (=read as). If this is not possible you could define a property which converts the string:

```
public DateTime Created_At_DateTime
{
   get
   {
      return DateTime.ParseExact(this.Created_At, "yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   }
   set
   {
      this.Created_At = value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   }
}
```

But you can't use this property in SQL-queries.. The other version neither, but debugging is a little bit harder with those ones.

Comment: OP should really use the correct datatype instead. But apart from that your  workaround contains a subtle localization issue. The [`/` format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#dateSeparator) will be replaced by the localized date-separator of the current culture. So if that is not `/` you will get a `FormatException` on the getter after you have used the setter the first time. To fix it you have to use `value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` or `value.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd")`(the apostrophes escape the format specifier).

Comment: You're right! Should have tried it before posting ;-).