# Filtering an Iqueryable object by a group of rules

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I've been filtetring an Iqueryable object by some rules, using successive `Where` clauses to do && filtering, how can i do the same for || filtering?
Anyone has a suggestion?

Using another words, i want to apply for all rules || filtering.

I'm going to show a portion of the code to exemplify what im asking.

Where i get the pages object:

```
    public IQueryable<gbd_Pages> getAllPagesByOrderAndDir(int template_id, string name = "", int sortOrder = 3, string sortDirection = "asc")
    {
        IQueryable<gbd_Pages> Listpages;
        if (sortDirection == "asc")
        {
            Listpages = from p in _db.gbd_Pages 
                        from pc in (from c in p.gbd_Content
                                    where c.IsActive == true && c.IsDeleted == false && c.Template_Id == template_id
                                    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) ? c.Content.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower()) : true
                                    && c.gbd_Template_Fields.SortOrder == sortOrder
                                    select c).Take(1)
                        orderby pc.Content ascending
                        where p.IsActive == true && p.IsDeleted == false
                        select p;
        }
        else
        {
            Listpages = from p in _db.gbd_Pages 
                        from pc in (from c in p.gbd_Content
                                    where c.IsActive == true && c.IsDeleted == false && c.Template_Id == template_id
                                    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) ? c.Content.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower()) : true
                                    && c.gbd_Template_Fields.SortOrder == sortOrder
                                    select c).Take(1)
                        orderby pc.Content descending
                        where p.IsActive == true && p.IsDeleted == false
                        select p;
        }
        return Listpages;
    }
```

The function where i do the filtering. Actually it's only doing && filtering for all rules:

```
    public IEnumerable<gbd_Pages> PagesFiltered(List<Rule> newRules, string search, int sortColumnId, string sortColumnDir, out int count)
    {
        GBD.FrontOffice.Controllers.SegmentsController segmentCtrl = new GBD.FrontOffice.Controllers.SegmentsController();
        var Pages = controller.getAllPagesByOrderAndDir(1, search, sortColumnId, sortColumnDir);

        if (newRules.Count > 0)//FILTRA A LISTAGEM DE ACORDO COM AS REGRAS
        {
            foreach (var rule in newRules)
            {
                if (rule.Value!=null)
                {
                    gbd_Template_Fields templateField = controller.getTemplateFieldById(1, rule.Template_Field_Id);
                    gbd_Segment_Operators segOperator = segmentCtrl.getOperatorById(rule.Operator_Id);
                    if (segOperator.Value == "==")//IGUALDADE
                        if (rule.Value.Trim() != "")
                        {
                            if (templateField != null && templateField.Field_Id == 3) //tipo data
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    DateTime test_datetime = DateTime.Parse(rule.Value); // testa se a data introduzida é valida
                                    Pages = Pages.Where(p => p.gbd_Content.Any(c => c.Templates_Fields_Id == rule.Template_Field_Id && c.IsActive == true && c.IsDeleted == false && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Content) && c.Content.Trim() == rule.Value.Trim())));
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                }
                            }
                            else if (templateField != null && templateField.Field_Id == 12 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(rule.Value))//Lista múltipla de valores
                            {
                                rule.Value = rule.Value.Replace(',', '|');
                                Pages = Pages.Where(p => p.gbd_Content.Any(c => c.Templates_Fields_Id == rule.Template_Field_Id && c.IsActive == true && c.IsDeleted == false && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Content) && c.Content == rule.Value)));
                            }
                            else
                                Pages = Pages.Where(p => p.gbd_Content.Any(c => c.Templates_Fields_Id == rule.Template_Field_Id && c.IsActive == true && c.IsDeleted == false && (c.Content != null && c.Content.ToLower().Trim() == rule.Value.ToLower().Trim())));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Pages = Pages.Where(p => !p.gbd_Content.Any(c => c.Templates_Fields_Id == rule.Template_Field_Id) || p.gbd_Content.Any(c => c.Templates_Fields_Id == rule.Template_Field_Id && c.IsActive == true && c.IsDeleted == false && (c.Content == null || c.Content.ToLower().Trim() == rule.Value.ToLower().Trim())));
                        }
                    else if (segOperator.Value == ">")//MAIOR QUE
                    {
                        if (templateField != null && templateField.Field_Id == 3) //tipo data
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                DateTime test_datetime = DateTime.Parse(rule.Value); // testa se a data introduzida é valida
                                Pages = Pages.Where(p => p.gbd_Content.Any(c => c.Templates_Fields_Id == rule.Template_Field_Id && c.IsActive == true && c.IsDeleted == false && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Content) && (c.Content.Substring(6, 4).CompareTo(rule.Value.Trim().Substring(6, 4)) > 0 || c.Content.Substring(6, 4).CompareTo(rule.Value.Trim().Substring(6, 4)) == 0 && c.Content.Substring(3, 2).CompareTo(rule.Value.Trim().Substring(3, 2)) > 0 || c.Content.Substring(6, 4).CompareTo(rule.Value.Trim().Substring(6, 4)) == 0 && c.Content.Substring(3, 2).CompareTo(rule.Value.Trim().Substring(3, 2)) == 0 && c.Content.Substring(0, 2).CompareTo(rule.Value.Trim().Substring(0, 2)) > 0))));
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                            }
                        }
                        else if (templateField != null && templateField.Field_Id == 5)//tipo número
                            Pages = Pages.Where(p => p.gbd_Content.Any(c => c.Templates_Fields_Id == rule.Template_Field_Id && c.IsActive == true && c.IsDeleted == false && (c.Content != null && c.Content != "" && (c.Content.Trim().CompareTo(rule.Value.Trim()) > 0 || (rule.Value.Trim().StartsWith("-") && c.Content.Trim().CompareTo(rule.Value.Trim()) > 0 || (c.Content.Trim().CompareTo("0") > 0))))));//procurar outra solução https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740693/big-issue-in-converting-string-to-datetime-using-linq-to-entities
                        else if (templateField != null && templateField.Field_Id == 6) //tipo telefone  //ESTA CONDIÇÃO NÃO FOI ADICIONADA AINDA A BD
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                Pages = Pages.AsEnumerable().Where(p => p.gbd_Content.Any(c => c.Templates_Fields_Id == rule.Template_Field_Id && c.IsActive == true && c.IsDeleted == false && (c.Content != null && c.Content != "" && (Convert.ToInt32(c.Content.Split(' ')[1]) > Convert.ToInt32(rule.Value))))).AsQueryable();//TODO: procurar outra solução
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex) { }
                        }
                    }
```

many more rules...

```
                    else if (segOperator.Value == "StartsWith")//COMEÇA COM
                    {
                        if (rule.Value.Trim() != "")
                            Pages = Pages.Where(p => p.gbd_Content.Any(c => c.Templates_Fields_Id == rule.Template_Field_Id && c.IsActive == true && c.IsDeleted == false && (c.Content != null && c.Content.ToLower().Trim().StartsWith(rule.Value.ToLower().Trim()))));
                    }
                    else if (segOperator.Value == "EndsWith")//ACABA COM
                    {
                        if (rule.Value.Trim() != "")
                            Pages = Pages.Where(p => p.gbd_Content.Any(c => c.Templates_Fields_Id == rule.Template_Field_Id && c.IsActive == true && c.IsDeleted == false && (c.Content != null && c.Content.ToLower().Trim().EndsWith(rule.Value.ToLower().Trim()))));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        count = Pages.Select(d => d.Id).Count();
        return Pages;
    }
```

Comment: do you want all of the rules applied as "or"?

Comment: Consider using LINQKit? It has tools to combine expressions dynamically then apply them in the `Where`.

Comment: This looks like a good candidate for [Dynamic LINQ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/). But another approach is to gradually build the predicate expression first and when it's finished use it to filter `Pages`.

Comment: @ohmusama yes i want to have all conditions applied as OR

Answer (score 0):

The `Where` statement is implicitly using `AND` in all cases. To get an `OR` statement equivalent, you'll need to use the double pipe operator (`||`) inside of a `Where` statement with something like:

```
.Where(p => p.A == 'b' || p.C == 'd')
```

Unfortunately there is no simple way to add successive optional statements the .NET framework. It would be great to have something like `.Where(p => p.A == 'b').Or(p => p.C == 'd')` but generating a query from this seems impractical - if there was an another `Where` statement, then how would Linq know how to group it relative to the other two? (A || B && C) versus ((A || B) && C).

That said, there is an external library (LINQKit) that can help fill the gap. See [Dynamic where clause (OR) in Linq to Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621450/dynamic-where-clause-or-in-linq-to-entities/14622200) for reference.

Comment: *there is no way to add successive optional statements* There is when using a predicate builder.

Comment: Predicate builder is still inserted into a Where clause though. But I'm rethinking this.

Comment: Yes, but the predicate can be a chain of `or` conditions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14622200/861716.

Comment: Right, it is an external library. I was thinking about this from the native .NET standpoint. Still, I'll update my answer. Thank you for the contribution @GertArnold.

Answer (score 0):

You can work around the limitations of linq by just adding all the results into a `List<>`

```
List<gbd_Pages> allPages = new List<gdb_Pages>();
foreach (var rule in newRules)
{
    IEnumerable<gbd_Pages> rulePages;

    // current logic (except you need to not overwrite the Pages variable)
    // instead of the pattern "Pages = Pages.Where( ..." use "rulePages = Pages.Where( ..."

    allPages.AddRange(rulePages);
}

return allPages;
```